# In Java, How do you stop a previous audio file when another audio file starts using key_events

Tags: java, audio, wav

I know about the clip.stop() method, however it doesn't seem to work within when I have it inside the key_events. It just causes an Error. Well I know why it causes the error. Because I'm asking it to essentially stop a clip that doesn't exist until a few lines later. But using this same logic or close to it if possible, how could I recode that so it knows to select the previous clip that was playing from a previous key_event. The functionality I'm intending for is: When F1 is pressed, a wav plays. When F2 is pressed, current wav STOPS, new wav STARTS. When F3 is pressed, current wav STOPS, new wav STARTS.  Etc etc etc.

```
            case KeyEvent.VK_F1:

                try {

                    //stop any sound
                    clip.stop();

                    sample = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getURL(filename));

                    //create a sound buffer
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                    //load the audio file
                    clip.open(sample);

                    //play sample
                    clip.start();

                } catch (MalformedURLException ez) {
                } catch (IOException ez) {
                } catch (LineUnavailableException ez) {
                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ez) {
                } catch (Exception ez) { }

                break;


            case KeyEvent.VK_F2:

                try {

                    //stop any sound
                    clip.stop();

                    sample = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getURL(filename2));

                    //create a sound buffer
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                    //load the audio file
                    clip.open(sample);

                    //play sample
                    clip.start();

                } catch (MalformedURLException ez) {
                } catch (IOException ez) {
                } catch (LineUnavailableException ez) {
                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ez) {
                } catch (Exception ez) { }

                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_F3:

                try {

                    //stop any sound
                    clip.stop();

                    sample = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getURL(filename3));

                    //create a sound buffer
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                    //load the audio file
                    clip.open(sample);

                    //play sample
                    clip.start();

                } catch (MalformedURLException ez) {
                } catch (IOException ez) {
                } catch (LineUnavailableException ez) {
                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ez) {
                } catch (Exception ez) { }

                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_F4:

                try {

                    //stop any sound
                    clip.stop();

                    sample = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getURL(filename4));

                    //create a sound buffer
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                    //load the audio file
                    clip.open(sample);

                    //play sample
                    clip.start();

                } catch (MalformedURLException ez) {
                } catch (IOException ez) {
                } catch (LineUnavailableException ez) {
                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ez) {
                } catch (Exception ez) { }

                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_F5:

                try {

                    //stop any sound
                    clip.stop();

                    sample = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getURL(filename5));

                    //create a sound buffer
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                    //load the audio file
                    clip.open(sample);

                    //play sample
                    clip.start();

                } catch (MalformedURLException ez) {
                } catch (IOException ez) {
                } catch (LineUnavailableException ez) {
                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ez) {
                } catch (Exception ez) { }

                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_F6:

                try {

                    //stop any sound
                    clip.stop();

                    sample = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getURL(filename6));

                    //create a sound buffer
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                    //load the audio file
                    clip.open(sample);

                    //play sample
                    clip.start();

                } catch (MalformedURLException ez) {
                } catch (IOException ez) {
                } catch (LineUnavailableException ez) {
                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ez) {
                } catch (Exception ez) { }

                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_F7:

                try {

                    //stop any sound
                    clip.stop();

                    sample = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getURL(filename7));

                    //create a sound buffer
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                    //load the audio file
                    clip.open(sample);

                    //play sample
                    clip.start();

                } catch (MalformedURLException ez) {
                } catch (IOException ez) {
                } catch (LineUnavailableException ez) {
                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ez) {
                } catch (Exception ez) { }

                break;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which would actually be a recommended solition. An actually [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: You're shadowing your variables, which won't help and you could simply check for `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to be 100% sure, but it looks like you are shadowing your variables...

```
clip.stop();

sample = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getURL(filename));

//create a sound buffer
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
```

In fact, I'm not even sure how this would compile...

Define `Clip` as an instance variable, when you program is initialised, initialise the `Clip` at the same time.

You should be able to call `stop` at any time, but this will only reset the `Clip` back to the start of the current input.  What you need to, also do, is close the `Clip`, which releases the internal resources been managed by the `Clip` for the current input...

`KeyListener`s are also notoriously troublesome and you should consider using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) as they provide you with the control to determine the focus level that the key events can be generated at, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestPlayer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPlayer();
    }

    public TestPlayer() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (LineUnavailableException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Clip clip;
        private List<File> playList;
        private int index;

        private JLabel label;

        public TestPane() throws LineUnavailableException {
            label = new JLabel("Play stuff");
            add(label);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

            File[] files = new File("A folder of music files").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File file) {
                    return file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".wav");
                }
            });
            playList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(files));
            index = -1;

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "previous");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "next");

            ActionMap am = getActionMap();
            am.put("next", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    playNext();
                }
            });
            am.put("previous", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    playPrevious();
                }
            });
        }

        public void playNext() {
            index++;
            if (index >= playList.size()) {
                index = 0;
            }

            File file = playList.get(index);

            play(file);
        }

        public void playPrevious() {
            index--;
            if (index < 0) {
                index = playList.size() - 1;
            }

            File file = playList.get(index);

            play(file);
        }

        public void play(File file) {

            try {
                stop();
                label.setText(file.getName());
                AudioInputStream sample = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
                clip.open(sample);
                clip.start();
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void stop() {

            clip.stop();
            clip.close();

        }

    }

}
```