# Sound problems in Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I have some questions about playing sound in Java and I hope you can help me out.
1. How can I stop a playing sound with a "Stop" button?
2. How can I slow down (or cooldown time) a sound?
3. I want to create a option frame where I can adjust volume and have mute option, how can I do that?
This is my code:

```
    private void BGM() {
        try {
            File file = new File(AppPath + "\\src\\BGM.wav");
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, and, Have a nice day!

Comment: Don't ever use a path which contains "src", the "src" won't exist after after the program is built/packaged. You'll need to use Class#getResource instead. Of the three questions you've asked. Which is most important to you? 1- Clip#stop

Comment: 1 & 3 [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232683/in-java-how-do-you-stop-a-previous-audio-file-when-another-audio-file-starts-us/23233016#23233016)

Comment: Thanks for replying and nice tips, MadProgrammer. My first problem is I can't use ClipStop (or I do not know how to use it, for exactly), I try to put it and ClipStart in If/Else statement (IN try/catch bock) to Start/Stop the sound when meeting condition (and I call it everytime I click the button), but It doesn't work. I read your example, but I can't call it out too. Sorry for my stupidity, Could you explain more? Thank you very much and have a nice day!

Comment: stop is a method of Clip, just like start is. You also need to make sure that you have reference to the instance of Clip you first created

Answer (score 1):

You're working in an Object Oriented programming lanuage, so let's take advantage of that and encapsulate the management of the clip/audio into a simple class...

```
public class AudioPlayer {

    private Clip clip;

    public AudioPlayer(URL url) throws IOException, LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url.openStream()));
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return clip != null && clip.isRunning();
    }

    public void play() {
        if (clip != null && !clip.isRunning()) {
            clip.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (clip != null && clip.isRunning()) {
            clip.stop();
        }
    }

    public void dispose() {
        try {
            clip.close();
        } finally {
            clip = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Now, to use it, you need to create a class instance field which will allow you to access the value from anywhere within the class you want to use it...

```
private AudioPlayer bgmPlayer;
```

Then, when you need it, you create an instance of `AudioPlayer` and assign it to this variable

```
try {
    bgmPlayer = new AudioPlayer(getClass().getResource("/BGM.wav"));
} catch (IOException | LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, when you need to, you simply call `bgmPlayer.play()` or `bgmPlayer.stop()`