# How to set play to a JButton one sound at a time in java?

Tags: java, swing, audio, jbutton, playback

I have been working on a project for few weeks now. [This is the Main Basic UI for the Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kahDL.png)

When User Press a button A relevant .wav file is playing but it wont't stop playing when user click another button. i want it to be stopped when user click another button.

Comment: Maintain a reference to the current `Clip`, call `Clip#stop` to stop it from playing before you create the next one

Comment: ........... and of course respect threading rules by running the clip in a background thread, and only making Swing calls on the Swing event thread.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Isn't `Clip#play` non-blocking?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: OK, you've got me there -- I had assumed incorrectly that it was blocking.

Comment: [As a runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232683/in-java-how-do-you-stop-a-previous-audio-file-when-another-audio-file-starts-us/23233016#23233016)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Always confuses the crap out of me :P

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make the current play to stop before another click ,i.e a play request comes in.

```
public void playClip(String clipName){
    if(audioPlayer.isPlaying()){
            audioPlayer.stop();
     }else{
            audioPlayer.setClip(clipName);
             audioPlayer.play();
 }// not actual code, but you get the idea
```

Comment: @Neo It is not working for my code. getting a lots of errors

Comment: Well, I just gave the idea, not actual code , it is also mentioned above :)

Comment: but that idea is not working for me, in my case. i am using the above UX design so user must be able to change the font name according to their own. i can't think of a way to do that from user code. @Neo